# OpenVPN Server access issue with two VPCs

Tags: networking, vpn, amazon-vpc, openvpn

I am trying to set up a OPenVPN server for my dev and prod env I have followed this article [here](https://dev.to/setevoy/openvpn-openvpn-access-server-set-up-and-aws-vpc-peering-configuration-5fpg). I have two Amazon VPC in same zone.
VPC A (CIDR 10.0.0.0/16)
VPC B (CIDR 10.1.0.0/16)
Dev Box (10.0.1.190)
Prod Box (10.1.2.83)
OpenVPN Server (10.0.0.53)
OpenVPN server is installed and configured in VPC A (10.0.0.53).
Have 2 private subnets in each zone. My Dev Box is in VPC A (Private IP= 10.0.1.190), Prod Box is in VPC B (Private IP = 10.1.2.83). I have VPC peering from VPC A (Requester) to VPC B (Accepter), Both VPC Route table is also updated to access each other. In VPN server I had set it up "Specify the private subnets to which all clients should be given access (one per line):
10.0.0.0/16
10.1.0.0/16
Security Group settings are below
Dev Security Group :- SSH 22 (10.0.0.0/16)
Prod Security Group :- SSH 22 (10.0.0.0/16)
Now I have downloaded OpenVPN client on windows box. I can access Dev Box form my workstation. I can access prod box from dev box. But somehow I am not able to access prod box from my local workstation.

**tracert 1.1.1.1**
Tracing route to one.one.one.one [1.1.1.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     3 ms     3 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     7 ms     3 ms     3 ms  abts-north-static-068.127.176.122.airtelbroadban
d.in [122.176.127.68]
  3     9 ms     5 ms     3 ms  125.17.145.1
  4    51 ms    48 ms    53 ms  182.79.142.252
  5   283 ms   319 ms   117 ms  182.79.223.58
  6    48 ms    48 ms    44 ms  one.one.one.one [1.1.1.1]

Trace complete.

**tracert 10.0.0.53**

Tracing route to 10.0.0.53 over a maximum of 30 hops

1   363 ms   362 ms   353 ms  10.0.0.53

Trace complete.

tracert 10.0.1.190

Tracing route to 10.0.1.190 over a maximum of 30 hops

1   337 ms   333 ms   334 ms  172.27.232.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *

**tracert 10.1.2.83**

Tracing route to 10.1.2.83 over a maximum of 30 hops

1   336 ms   333 ms   333 ms  172.27.232.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.

**Some Logs in installation folder**

Tunnel Addresses:
  172.27.240.132/20 -> 172.27.240.1
Reroute Gateway: IPv4=0 IPv6=0 flags=[ ENABLE AUTO_LOCAL DEF1 BYPASS_DHCP BYPASS_DNS IPv4 ]
Block IPv6: yes
Route Metric Default: 101
Add Routes:
  172.27.224.0/20
  10.0.0.0/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, your peering between VPC A and VPC B is working as expected but you are not able to establish connection between your local workstation and production box.

As you mentioned earlier you are able to access your Dev box in VPC A from your local workstation, you can try to compare the configuration of the Routing table of Private subnet having your Dev Box with the Routing table to private Subnet having your production box. The changes in the Routing tables can be made similar and then you can try the connectivity again from your local workstation

Design-wise it good to have your current arrangement of accessing Prod Box via Dev box but I admit it is important to understand the why the connectivity is not established.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, Yes design wise its good to access prod via Dev Box, But actually prod url would be in private subnet and user logged in VPN network, would only be able to access sites. I have checked subnets, security groups in both VPC looks good.

Comment: Actually I found the solution, The route table of VPN server was missing vpc peering entry. I only updated Dev route table.